# hop to hop communication

Tags: networking, communication, router

If we are in the same network, then hop to hop communication takes place by layer-2 devices such as switches, bridges, *etc.* that work at the MAC layer.

But if we have to send packets to a destination in some other network then hop to hop communication takes place through routers.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statements are conceptually correct, though the details are not quite right.

A layer 3 protocol like IP can route a packet from its source to its destination across the entire Internet, but a layer 2 protocol like ethernet can only route packets for a single hop.  When a device transmits a packet on a TCP/IP network, it must know the ethernet (layer 2) address of the next hop and the IP (layer 3) address of the packet's final destination.

Let's look at the two cases you describe, using a scenario where a user on Device A knows the IP address of Device B and wants to send it a packet.

**Devices on the same (unswitched) subnet**

1. The user on Device A issues the command `ping 10.1.1.23`.
2. Device A broadcasts an ARP (layer 2) request, asking which device on its network can route a packet to IP address 10.1.1.23.
3. Device B recognizes the IP address as its own and answers the request by returning a packet with its IP and ethernet addresses as the source, and Device A's IP and ethernet addresses as the destination.
4. Now Device A has everything it needs to communicate with Device B.  Every packet it transmits to Device B will have the proper ethernet and IP addresses as the destination.

**Devices on the same (switched) subnet**

1. The user on Device A issues the command `ping 10.1.1.23`.
2. Device A broadcasts an ARP (layer 2) request, asking which device on its network can route a packet to IP address 10.1.1.23.
3. A switch receives the packet on one of its ports and retransmits the *same* packet on whichever port is connected to Device B.  **This is the only significant difference between switched and unswitched subnets.**
4. Device B recognizes the IP address as its own and answers the request by returning a packet with its IP and ethernet addresses as the source, and Device A's IP and ethernet addresses as the destination.
5. Now Device A has everything it needs to communicate with Device B.  Every packet it transmits to Device B will have the proper ethernet and IP addresses as the destination.

**Devices on different subnets**

1. The user on Device A issues the command `ping 8.8.8.8`.
2. Device A broadcasts an ARP (layer 2) request, asking which device on its network can route a packet to IP address 8.8.8.8.
3. The address 8.8.8.8 is on a different network, so no local device recognizes the address as its own.  However, a router sees the packet, checks its routing tables, and sees that it knows how to forward packets to the 8.8.8.x network.  So the router replies by returning a packet that has its own ethernet address as the source.
4. Now Device A can communicate with Device B by sending packets that have a destination IP address of 8.8.8.8, but the *router's* ethernet address as their destination.
5. The router receives the packets because they are destined for its ethernet (layer 2) address, but it notices that their destination IP (layer 3) addresses are different from its own, and so it forwards them to whatever address is stored in its routing table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. To access other networks (networks on a different subnet) a client will route the traffic to its default gateway, which will encapsulate the traffic and route appropriately. For communicating on the same network only a layer 2 switch is required.

Comment: Actually, to communicate on the same network segment, _nothing_ beyond the two hosts is required.  A layer 2 switch may provide filtering but is not necessary for connectivity.

Comment: I agree. Just a crossover cable or a straight thru cable and one of the two NIC cards capable of MDIX-Auto.